# Mongodb: Find ids $in nested array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have the following data structure for my users in my mongodb:

```
{
    _id: "someId",
    profile: {
        username: "oliv",
        friendRequests: [
            { fromUserId: "anId", accepted: false, created: "someDate"},
            { fromUserId: "otherId", accepted: true, created: "otherDate"}
        ]
}
```

I'd like to **retrieve the user objects that are referenced in my logged user's friendsRequested**.
So I tried something like this:

```
Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: Meteor.user().profile.friendRequests.fromUserId}});
// FYI: Meteor.users is the collection and Meteor.user() retrieves the current user
```

But it's not working. I'm assuming it's because of the nested array.
 Is there any way of telling mongo to iterate through the fromUserId or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: _.pluck(Meteor.user().profile.friendRequests, 'fromUserId') }});
```

Reasoning:

`friendRequests` is an array of objects, and $in wants an array of strings(the ids), using `_.pluck` you're able to pass an array of objects, and tell `_` to only return the field `fromUserId` for each object in the array.

Question in comment ("what if I only want to get the ids from friend requests where "accepted" is false?"):

```
_.pluck(
    _.filter(Meteor.user().profile.friendRequests, function (req) {
        return !req.accepted;
    }),
    'fromUserid'
);
```

[Underscore filter docs](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Now I just have another question if you don't mind: what if I only want to get the ids from friend requests where "accepted" is false?

Comment: I updated my answer, if you wouldn't mind accepting the answer that'd be great :) Underscore is a great library. I highly suggest looking over all the Collection functions in the docs and really try to understand what their purpose is and how to use them.

Comment: I though it was working at first but it seems it's throwing a huge list of errors in fact (and not just with the filter, even the simple pluck) -> See edit (But thank you for the answer)

Comment: Could you please post the results of this: console.log(JSON.stringify({_id: {$in: _.pluck(Meteor.user().profile.friendRequests, 'fromUserId') }}); right before the line that throws the error.

Comment: Hmm that line is in a return{requests: ->query } so I don' know how to do that...

Comment: Oh so sorry it seems like another query is producing this error. Because I am looking for users with ids $in my profile.friends array but for some users, that array doesn't exist yet. Is there a way of doing an $in if the property exists? I assumed that it checked by default

Comment: no, you'll have to guard for those kind of things, "if (Meteor.user().friends) { }"

Comment: Hey. So I fixed the other query and now the _pluck query works fine. Somehow though the query with _filter doesn't work but I finally got it with a _where. Like this: Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: _.pluck(_.where(Meteor.user().profile.friendRequests, {accepted:false}), 'fromUserId')}});